# JsonSerializer calling container Equals override method

Tags: c#, json, serialization, polymorphism, overriding

First of all had a good look around and understand override/virtual etc. But haven't found any cases specific to my situation - which I'm sure isn't unique. I want to just make sure the implementation I go with is the right implementation. I have the following code setup to demonstrate my issue:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

namespace Sandpit
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var fixture = new Fixture
                {
                    Name = "Fixture Name",
                    Participants = new List<Participant> {new Participant {Name = "Participant Name"}}
                };

            var writer = new StringWriter(new StringBuilder());
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
            serializer.Serialize(writer, fixture);

            Console.Write(writer.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Fixture
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Participant> Participants { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var fixture = (Fixture)obj;

            return fixture.Name == Name;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Name.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    public class Participant
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var participant = (Participant)obj;

            return participant.Name == Name;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Name.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Now when this runs I get an exception on `var fixture = (Fixture)obj;`.

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Sandpit.Participant]' to type
>   'Sandpit.Fixture'.

I don't understand why it is getting into there. And why this breaks the correct implementation of overridden `object` methods.

I know that I can fix this by doing `public new bool Equals(object obj)`. Am I doing this right? Also these objects are well integrated into the application I am working on, is there likely to be any side effects to making this change?

Many thanks,
Matt

Comment: Another alternative is to use "obj as Fixture/Participant" then check if null. Seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small change to your `Fixture` and `Participant` classes fixes this:

```
public class Fixture 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Participant> Participants { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var fixture = obj as Fixture;
        return fixture == null ? false : fixture.Name == Name;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class Participant 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var participant = obj as Participant;
        return participant == null ? false : participant.Name == Name;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

If you are comparing to an element that's of another type, you can be certain that the two are not equal.

Comment: I've decided to go with putting the contents of the public bool Equals method after the null check in the override. Could you update your answer if this sounds okay?

Comment: The problem, as I see it, is that an object of a different type is sent into the Equals method. Why anyone would send in a different type of object in an Equals method is a bit odd to say the least, but to check for that in every case is a headache. the Equals method shouldnt ever get called with a different object type.

Comment: @Ted Overrding operators like == and != also requires you to overload Equals. Calling Equals when you know the object is different is of course nonsense. But the purpose of Equals (or ==, !=) is when you don't know. So it makes total sense to call it with a different object since you don't know everything at compile time. Also have a look at IEquatable<T> (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1.equals?view=netframework-4.7#System_IEquatable_1_Equals__0_) where a generic Equals<T> is used.